# ASP.NET Button click call Javascript function in BeginForm and stop form submit

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have this situation:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNewApplication", "Token", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label for="app-name" class="op-form op-label">Application:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.appName, new { @placeholder = "Nome dell'applicazione", @class = "op-form op-text app-name" })<br />
    <label for="token" class="op-form op-label">Token:</label>
    <button id="generate-token" class="op-form" value="Genera Token">Generate Token</button>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.appToken, new { @placeholder = "Token", @id = "token", @class = "op -form op-text token" })<br />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" class="op-form op-submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

and the button call this Javascript function:

```
$('#generate-token').click(function () {
    var token = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
    $("#token").val(token);
});
```

The problem is that when click the button, the Javascript function is correctly called, but also is called the CreateNewToken method in my Token controller. While I want only call Javascript on click button and call method controller when click submit.
Is possible to do? How?

Comment: you should use preventDefault() - see http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp

`$('#generate-token').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var token = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
        $("#token").val(token);
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

> Inside a "form" element the default behaviour of a button when type is not mentioned is "submit"

hence your form is getting submitted as soon as you click the button.

**Solution:**
Add the `type="button"` attribute into your `button` element.

`<button id="generate-token" type="button" class="op-form" value="Genera Token">Generate Token</button>`

Source http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp